# Nativescript 6.0 Android App Widget not working

Tags: javascript, android, widget, nativescript

I'm trying to use an app widget with NativeScript 6.0 Core.
I've used the example code provided from Nativescript:
[sample-Android-Widgets](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Android-Widgets)

It compiles and works good, but when I try to place the widget on the screen, I get the following error:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to instantiate receiver com.tns.MyWidget: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'com/tns/MyWidget'
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.tns.MyWidget: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'com/tns/MyWidget'
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3365)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:199)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'com/tns/MyWidget'
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstanceNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstance(Runtime.java:778)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.initInstance(Runtime.java:751)
System.err:     at com.tns.MyWidget.<init>(MyWidget.java:13)
System.err:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
System.err:     at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(AppComponentFactory.java:84)
System.err:     at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(CoreComponentFactory.java:56)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3358)
System.err:     ... 8 more
```

I'm having troubles since I update NativeScript to the new 6.0 version.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's possible your widget's native class was not complied properly, did you include the class in webpack config?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No I didn't include, can you please tell me how to add in webpack config?

Comment: Did you check the webpack config file? If you read the comments in the file, it reads you will have to add the custom activities, services etc., to `appComponents` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Manoj!
I figured it! I was near the answer, in webpack config but didn't know what kind of path insert in `appComponents`.

This documentation helped me definitely [Extend Application Activity](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity)

That's what I edited in `webpack.config`

```
const appComponents = [
        ...
        resolve(__dirname, "app/<MyFile>.js"),
    ];
```

Thank you again!